Error using Pnp to disable page comments
I'm trying to use the following to disable comments on all pages within a site:
#Parameter
$SiteURL= "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing/2018"
$LibraryName = "SitePages"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Get all Pages from the Library
$Pages = Get-PnPListItem -List $LibraryName | Where { $_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File"}
 
#Loop through each Page
ForEach($Page in $Pages)
{
    #Disable Comments
    Write-host "Disabling Comments on page:"$Page["FileLeafRef"]
    Set-PnPPage -Identity $Page["FileLeafRef"] -CommentsEnabled:$False
}

I'm getting the following error on pages that have full width sections:
You cannot host text controls inside a one column full width section, only an image web part or hero web part are allowed
If I remove the full width section from individual pages and run the script the comments are disabled as required.
Is there a way of amending the script so it works on all pages including those with full width sections?
